# Fill the content of newly added Profile Tab (BuddyPress)

Tags: buddypress

I have added a new tab for profile tab using following code.

```
add_action('bp_setup_nav', 'mb_bp_profile_menu_posts', 301 );
function mb_bp_profile_menu_posts() {
global $bp;
bp_core_new_nav_item(
    array(
        'name' => 'My Posts',
        'slug' => 'posts', 
        'position' => 11, 
        'default_subnav_slug' => 'published', // We add this submenu item below 
        'screen_function' => 'mb_author_posts'
    )
);
}
```

I need to show 5 latest posts from the user in this tab. How to do it? (Currently when click the “My Posts” tab it says 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code below. I guess you are facing 404 because it's not getting the `slug` & the `url` properly.

```
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'mb_bp_profile_menu_posts' );
function mb_bp_profile_menu_posts() {
    global $bp;
    bp_core_new_nav_item(
        array(
            'name'                => 'My Posts',
            'slug'                => 'myposts',
            'position'            => 11,
            'default_subnav_slug' => 'published',
            'screen_function'     => 'mb_author_posts',
            'parent_url'          => bp_displayed_user_domain() . '/myposts/',
            'parent_slug'         => $bp->profile->slug,
            'default_subnav_slug' => 'myposts',
        )
    );
}

function mb_author_posts() {
    add_action( 'bp_template_title', 'mb_author_posts_title' );
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'mb_author_posts_content' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'buddypress/members/single/plugins' );
}

function mb_author_posts_title() {
    echo 'My Posts';
}

function mb_author_posts_content() {
    echo 'Content logic goes here...';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

BuddyPress plugin provides support for this question. This link will help you.
https://buddypress.org/support/topic/creating-a-page-with-nav-tab-subnav-for-buddypress-profiles/